# Deploy Vue to GitHub Pages. Error with vue-router

Tags: vue.js, github-pages, vue-router, vue-cli

I was experiencing some trouble while deploying a Vue application build with vue-cli v3.0. to GitHub Pages. I'm using [subtree](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490) to send the `dist` folder only to `gh-pages` branch. First the problem was that the [assets where not found](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/976) but I fixed it using `baseUrl` on `vue.config.js`. Now the problem is that the `#app` element is empty. I found out that if I don't use `vue-router` (render the view direct instead of using `<router-view/>`) the app works fine with GitHub pages. I believe there is some issue with the route `path` option but I'm unable to figure out how to fix it.

The repository with the issue is https://github.com/guizoxxv/vue-cli-deploy and the GitHub Page link is https://guizoxxv.github.io/vue-cli-deploy/

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I discovered the cause for this issue:

As GitHub Pages URL is not served from the root

`https://guizoxxv.github.io/vue-cli-deploy/` has `vue-cli-deploy/` after the root `/`

I need to specify a `base` option for my app on `vue-router` options. Here is the documentation https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base

Answer (score 5):

**Update 2020**

> `baseUrl` is Deprecated since Vue CLI 3.3, please use `publicPath` instead.

If you are using Vue CLI >= 3.3 you might want to check out [this vue-cli plugin](https://github.com/Rolanddoda/vue-cli-plugin-gh-pages-auto-deploy) which automates github pages deployment using github actions.

> By default, Vue CLI assumes your app will be deployed at the root of a domain, e.g. https://www.my-app.com/. If your app is deployed at a sub-path, you will need to specify that sub-path using this option. For example, if your app is deployed at https://www.foobar.com/my-app/, set baseUrl to '/my-app/'. So :

1. Create a new file in root directory of your project and name it ‘vue.config.js’
2. In ‘vue.config.js’ file paste the following code:

   `module.exports = { baseUrl: ‘/my-first-project/’ }`

NOTE: in baseUrl inside the // chars you have to put the name of your project.

Read more [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js)

> Also, read a full article how to deploy vue.js project in github pages [here](https://dev.to/rolanddoda/deploy-to-github-pages-like-a-pro-with-github-actions-4hdg)

Comment: The `baseUrl` property is now deprecated. We should use `publicPath` instead. https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath

Comment: The OP asked about vue-cli 3.0. `baseUrl` deprecated in 3.3. However I updated my answer

Comment: Yes, I saw that the question was made back in '18. It was just a reminder that it is now deprecated. :)

Answer (score 4):

1. For `Vue3`, Please make the configuration as below:

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory('/your-github-repo/'),
  routes: [
   // put your routes
  ]
});
```

2. For `Vue2`, Please make the configuration as below:

```js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: '/your-github-repo/',
  routes: [
    // put your routes
  ]
});
```

If still problem persists, please create `vue.config.js` file in root location of your vue app and add the following code:

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  ? '/your-github-repo/' // note the trailing slash
  : '/',
}
```

- [Vue base option moved - resource](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#moved-the-base-option)
- [Public path - resource](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath)

Answer (score 0):

can you try this in your main.js

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    components: { App },
    template: '<App/>',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As they said `baseUrl` is deprecated, use `publicPath`

```
module.exports = { publicPath: '/your-repo/' }
```